# how to save data before fragment is recreate?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i try to save data using  onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) method in fragment sub class .

Explanations:
    i create a class FragmentA which extends Fragment in this class i have a variable name count, value of count is change when i click button (initially count=0) i want to save the value of count even the orientation change (portrait to landscape or vice versa) .
And my MainActivity class load fragment Dynamically .

my code:

This Class Extends Fragment:-

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
Button change_After_Click;
    int count=0;
    Communicator com;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            count=savedInstanceState.getInt("counter",0);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("onActivityCreated");
        com= (Communicator) getActivity();
        change_After_Click=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textChangeClick);
        change_After_Click.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

count=count+1;
        com.proviedLinkBothFragment("button click "+ count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("counter",count);
    }
}
```

MainActivity class here i load fragment dynamically:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator {
Button btn;
    FragmentManager   fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    FragmentB obj;
    FragmentA objA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        System.out.println("ge low");


                    fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout,new FragmentA());

                    fragmentTransaction.commit();




    }



    @Override
    public void proviedLinkBothFragment(String s) {

           FragmentB fb= (FragmentB) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        fb.changeText(s);


    }


}
```

Comment: `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout,new FragmentA());` you are putting a new fragment each time. your save/load `count` looks right, but since you are replacing the fragment you don't see it. you need to check if the fragment is already there first.

Comment: @njzk2 can u please give me the code so i can understand easily .i'm new

Answer (score 0):

In activity's method `onCreate` you should check if fragment already exists before replace it. When you add a fragment you should use a tag for this fragment ("MY_TAG") and later you can find a fragment by a tag. You don't need to manually recreate a fragment (during rotation I guess). System makes it for you.

```
fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MY_TAG") == null) {
    fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.relativeLayout,new FragmentA(), "MY_TAG");

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```